# Transform a table with node levels in Excel

Tags: excel, transformation

How could I achieve a transformation of the data from Table 1 to Table 2.

Can an "=offset()" formula help in this case?

[image]

[Link to excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvtrstaw0lot3gr/Transform%20Table.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Better to just write a macro to scan the table and delete all but the last occurrence of AAA, and select the "Shift cells to the right" option in the code. Fire up the Macro Recorder, delete some cells manually, and see what the resulting code looks like. Will need to be amended, so if you don't know VBA you are not going to be able to do this yourself.

Comment: Don't put [Solved] in your title; accept the answer that solved your problem (once the system lets you) by clicking the check mark underneath the voting arrows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question stuck in my head. Could not resist solving it.
First, count unique values in a row (Nodes + Parent). In cell N3 enter the formula and fill it down:
`=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(B3:L3,B3:L3&""))`

<sup>details on how the formula works: https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif</sup>

Next, go to L15 and insert numbering for each level: 1 as Parent, 2 - Node 1, ..., 11 - Node 10.

In L17 enter the formula and copy it to the whole range B17:J25

`=IF(L$15<=$N3,OFFSET($B3,0,$N3-L$15);"")`

The formula works the following way. It anchors at the Node 10 value for each row. Depending on how many unique values there are in the row, it extracts values from left to right. For example, if you have 4 unique values in the Apple row (including Parent), the formula will only extract values from columns B,C,D,E.

I may lack words to describe the process, have a look at the table:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/n1y53v3nye3n47p/Transform%20Table.xlsx?dl=0

[image: Finally, Table 2 looks like this]

Comment: I'm really impressed by your solution. Really fun to see only excel formula and really useful if you want to skip VBA/xlsm file.
Thanks again for your time and effort :)

Answer (score 0):

So here is the code I wrote to solve the problem:

```
Sub MacroTest()

Dim iVal As Integer
Dim SearchValue As String
Dim WholeRange As String
Dim RangePart As String
Dim EndColumnToCut As Integer
Dim PasteCell As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turn off window update while running macro

X = 3 'Row to start from
Y = 12 'Column Value where the table ends


Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(X, Y)) 'Start at Row X and loop through column Y

If IsError(ActiveSheet.Cells(X, Y)) Then 'Check if cell(X,Y) returns error code, if yes then skip current code
    GoTo NextRow
Else
    SearchValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(X, Y).Value 'Find the value in cell (X,Y)


    iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B" & X, "L" & X), SearchValue) 'Count how many times the value in "SearchValue" appears (You want to remove duplicates and leave one unique value)
    Cells_To_Remove = iVal - 1 'delete all cells with the same value except one

        If Cells_To_Remove = 0 Then 'If "Cells_To_Remove" is equal to 0, i.e. there are no cells to remove, then go to next row
            GoTo NextRow 'Skip cut and paste values and jump to next row

        Else

            RemoveValuesInRange = Range(Cells(X, Y - Cells_To_Remove + 1), Cells(X, Y)).ClearContents 'Clear Contents in the range
            RemoveFormatInRange = Range(Cells(X, Y - Cells_To_Remove + 1), Cells(X, Y)).ClearFormats 'Clear formats in range


            EndColumnToCut = Y - Cells_To_Remove 'Define the last column in range to cut data
            RangePart = Range(Cells(X, 2), Cells(X, EndColumnToCut)).Select 'Define the whole range where the data should be cut
            Selection.Cut 'Cut data

            PasteCell = Cells(X, 2 + Cells_To_Remove).Select 'Define the cell where to paste the data
            ActiveSheet.Paste 'Paste Data

        End If
End If
GoTo NextRow 'Jump to next row
NextRow:
  X = X + 1 'Jump to next row
Loop
End Sub
```